# BroadCast receiver on boot

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm starting with android and I'm having some lessons to learn some android concepts. In this case, I'm practicing with the BroadCast receivers.

I have to create a BroadCast Receiver that when I boot the phone/emulator, starts an activity which shows a plain text.

I have this class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        IntentFilter mfilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED);
        registerReceiver(receiver, mfilter);
    }
};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
}
```

But i'm not getting to do what I need, it simply does nothing, so... What I'm doing wrong here?

In the manifest I just have the activity declared.

Comment: I think your broadcast receiver is not registered properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

Step1: 
set the permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Step2:
Add this is intent filter in receiver,

```
<receiver android:name=".BootReciever">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />

    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Step3:
Now you can start your application's first activity from onReceive method of Receiver class..

```
public class BootReciever extends BroadcastReceiver
{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    context.startActivity(myIntent);
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks, That was by doubt, If I would have to create a class for the receiver of if i could do all programmatically in the same class

Comment: still 3 minits left for that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can not register ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED receiver dynamically(it's not a way). 
ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED receiver has to be registered statically in manifest file

ex

```
   <receiver android:name="com.myapp.receiver.BootReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: But then, should I have to create another class extending BroadcastReceiver and declaring it on the manifest with that IntentFileter? I'm not sure how to doing this

Answer (score 0):

When you register a receiver in Activity or in Service it's lifetime is bound with them
You need to define your receiver inside app manifest.

For ex:

Class

```
class MyClass extends BroadCastReceiver{
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        IntentFilter mfilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED);
        registerReceiver(receiver, mfilter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your own MyReceiver class by extending BroadcastReceiver class, and register your MyReceiver in the manifest with filter ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.

```
 <receiver android:name="com.test.MyReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```